# How can I solve an equation independent of a variable?

Tags: equation-solving

Let's say I have the equation
$$
ax + b = 0
$$
and I'd like to find a solution that doesn't depend on $x$, so here the solution is obviously $a=b=0$. I could solve this using

```
Solve[{(a x + b == 0)/.{x->1},(a x + b == 0)/.{x->2}},x],
```

or some other favourite values for $x$, but it seems there should be a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think I've done wrong here; I'm not 'playing' with mathematica, I'm using it for work and learning more about how best to use it as I go, and I was under the impression that this site was a place for people using mathematica to ask questions and get help from people who knew more about the tool.

Having said that, SolveAlways seems to do exactly what I need so thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: "…you shouldn't play with *Mathematica*…" - well damn, playing with it is what I've exactly been doing for the past few decades, and look how I turn— never mind. :)

Comment: I'm also not really sure what Artes meant with his comment. Your question was asked politely and formatted correctly. The only problem he may have had with your question is that it is pretty basic and is answered in the documentation. Take for instance the `Solve` documentation page and open the "Properties & Relations" section and you'll find the needed tip to solve your problem. The documentation is huge though, so we can't really demand that everyone has read everything and this info wasn't really prominently there.

Comment: With all respect to Artes, playing with Mma is a great fun! We should not deprive ourselves of it.

Comment: Since you  had an approach working with `Solve`, the `See Also` section of the documentation for `Solve` would be a reasonable place to start. There you would have found `SolveAlways`.

Comment: @Guess Artes doesn't want you to have any fun.  No toys!  http://i.stack.imgur.com/aXaU7.jpg

Comment: I thought I had looked at the solve documentation, and I had tried googling, but I'd not managed to find the answer. Clearly I hadn't been careful enough in my reading of the documentation though, I think it's fair to point that out at least.

Should I write an answer based on @Artes comment so I can mark this as answered, or Artes would you like to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using [`SolveAlways`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html), you can use [`ForAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll.html) and [`Resolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html).

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, a x + b == 0]]
(* a == 0 && b == 0 *)
```

You might find this tutorial on [Quantifiers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Quantifiers.html) quite useful.